How to set \belowdisplayskip to zero *only* for the last equation of an ```\item``` bullet point?
Consider the code below:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\parskip}

\begin{itemize}

    \item This is some text. This some text. This is some text.
    \[a = b + c\]
    This is some text. This some text. This is some text.
    \[a = b + c\]

    \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}
    \item  This is some text. This some text. This is some text.
    \[a = b + c\]
    
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}
This is some text. This some text. This is some text.

\end{document}

\vspace{-\belowdisplayskip} ensures that the text lines are evenly spaced. Otherwise, the spacing after the second and third displayed math equations would be too large (or larger than \parskip as \belowdisplayskip is added).
Question: Is there a way to automate this spacing correction with an if-else-condition in the preamble? That is: it checks if an equation is immediately followed by an \item. If so, it temporarily sets \belowdisplayskip to zero.

Once the equa;tion ends, no trace remains.  It actually uses a trivlist environment.  Even \lastskip=0pt.
